# What is the difference between setting a private variable using this operator and normal assignment

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass {

    private char e; 

    public void intializeVariable(char z) {
       this.e = z;
    }
     public void intializeVariableWithoutThis(char z) {
       e = z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass mC =  new MyClass();
        System.out.println(mC.e);
        mC.intializeVariable('m');
        System.out.println(mC.e);
        mC.intializeVariableWithoutThis('n');
        System.out.println(mC.e);
    }

}
```

The methods initializeVariable and initailizeVariableWithoutThis are doing the same thing I just want to understand what is the difference in setting the value using this.e = z and just doing e = z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference but if you use a parameter with same name as a class variable then you have to use **this** keyboard

```
public void intializeVariable(char e) {
   this.e = e;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, yes other answers came when I've been typing this answer and I didn't see them before posting this answer

Comment: Thats ok. You never know if some answer might have some additional information. And I have to also wait till 7 minutes mark one as a correct one.

Answer (score 4):

This is used to indicate a field of current object.

```
public void intializeVariable(char z) {
   this.e = z;
}
```

If you change the above method to

```
 public void intializeVariable(char e) {
   this.e = e;
}
```

This will work normally. Compiler will know the "e"  is the parameter and the this.e is the field of the object.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, there is no difference, because each of them assigns `z` to `e`.

It would only make a difference if the name of the parameter was the same exact name of the instance variable, e.g. both were named `e`.

```
public void initializeVariableSameName(char e){
    this.e = e;
}
```

In that case, `e` refers to the parameter `e` and not the instance variable `e`.  It shadows the instance variable `e`.  That means that the only way to access the instance variable is by qualifying it with `this`, e.g. `this.e`.

The other case:

```
    e = e;
```

would assign the parameter `e` to itself; nothing useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need to explicitly say that `e` is one of the field of `this.` instance because in current scope there are no other variables called `e` so you can skip `this.` part (it will be added by compiler automatically). But if your method signature would look like

```
public void intializeVariable(char e) {
    ..
}
```

and you would like to assign value passed as `e` argument to *field* `e` you would need to write it as

```
this.e = e; 
//   ^   ^-- methods local variable
//   |
//   +------ field
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)
The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

Each argument to the constructor shadows one of the object's fields — inside the constructor x is a local copy of the constructor's first argument. To refer to the Point field x, the constructor must use this.x.
```